# format labels of enumerate

Tags: enumerate, labels

Consider this script:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
  \item item 1
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like the labels to be "1)" instead of "1." as per default. Therefore I use `[label=\arabic*)]` following p. 3 at http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf

However, when I compile there is an error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@* 
l.4 \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You have to use `enumitem` package, not `enumerate`.

Comment: @JouleV, is the same possible for `enumerate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`enumerate` and `enumitem` are *different* packages. Don't use them at the same time, and don't confuse them!**

If you want to use `enumerate` package, the only way is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1)]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `enumitem` is a little more complicated. However, you are using it correctly:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem} % NOT enumerate!
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

(same output as above)

or if you want to have the simple syntax of `enumerate`, you may need `shortlabels` option:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1)]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

(same output as above)

I often use the last way listed here. You have three options, choose whatever you want.