# begin penalty and label control with enumerate

Tags: lists, page-breaking, enumerate, enumitem

Using a begin penalty ([Avoid a break between a list and its introductory statement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487331/avoid-a-break-between-a-list-and-its-introductory-statement?answertab=active#tab-top)) works with `enumerate`

How to format labels with the `enumerate` environment was discussed in [format labels of enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483624/format-labels-of-enumerate?answertab=active#tab-top)

Using a begin penalty and label formatting with `enumerate` at the same time poses a conundrum. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[bottom=1cm, top =1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{enumitem}                                                          
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\lipsum[5][1-5]

another paragraph

consider the following cases:
\begin{enumerate}[1), beginpenalty=10000]
\item case 1
\item case 2
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[6-7]
\end{document}
```

First it compiles only when commenting out the line

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

However, the package `enumitem` must be supplied for using `beginpenalty=10000`. Can you help?

Comment: Replace `enumerate` with `enumtem` (option `[shortlabels]`).

Comment: @Bernard, do you mean `enumitem`? This environment is undefined even with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. Which environment is undefined?

Comment: @Bernard, the environment `enumitem` is undefined even with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: There is no enumitem environment: it's a package to customise standard lists and defines newlists if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[bottom=1cm, top =1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]
\lipsum[5][1-5]

another paragraph

consider the following cases:
\begin{enumerate}[1), beginpenalty=10000]
\item case 1
\item case 2
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can better exploit `enumitem` features:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[bottom=1cm, top =1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\lipsum[5][1-5]

another paragraph

consider the following cases:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*), beginpenalty=10000]
\item case 1
\item case 2
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[6-7]
\end{document}
```

The advantage over `shortlabels` is that you can separately set `label` and `ref` and more overall flexibility.

[image]